# Metrizability of a subset in the weak topology.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space (not reflexive). It is well-known that $(X,w)$, which is $X$ with its weak topology, is not metrizable if $X$ is infinite dimensional.

> I want to know under which condition can a subset $S\subset X$ be given a metric that is compatible with the weak topology $(S,w)$?

If $X$ is reflexive then, if I recall correctly, the norm-boundedness of $S$ is enough. However, I am dealing with a non-reflexive space $X=W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ so the previous criterion is not applicable. What if I assume that $S$ is norm-compact? Would that be enough?

Comment: Norm-boundedness is not enough, even if $X$ is reflexive. You also need a countable separating set in $X'$. For that, separability of $X'$ suffices, but is not a necessary condition, separability of $X$ is enough. For non-reflexive $X$, the same argument yields metrisability of relatively weakly compact subsets, if $X'$ contains a countable separating set.

Comment: For a norm-compact $S$, the answer is always "yes, it's metrisable in the weak topology". For the restriction of the weak topology is a coarser Hausdorff topology on $S$ than the restriction of the norm topology, but that is compact, hence every coarser Hausdorff topology on $S$ is identical to it. So on norm-compact subsets, the weak topology and the norm topology coincide.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you, my first reaction to this problem was to look up theorems regarding metrizability like the one Rhys suggested below. It didn't occur to be that standard topological argument is enough to solve it.

Comment: @DanielFischer May I ask 1 more related question? I suppose that if I only require $S$ to be precompact (in norm) then it would inherit the metric (which is equivalent to the weak topology on $S$) from its norm closure right? If I denote the said metric space by $(S,d)$, then would its metric completion coincide with its norm-closure in $X$.?

Comment: The weak topology and the norm topology coincide on every subset of a compact set. But the completion depends not only on the induced topology, it depends on the used metric. If you use the restriction of a metric on $\overline{S}$ (which induces the topology), then $\overline{S}$ is a completion; if you use a different metric, the completion can be different.

Comment: @DanielFischer Suppose that there are two metrics, says $d_1, d_2$ such that both are equivalent to the weak topology on $S$, are you saying that the completion with respect to these metrics could be different (as a subset of $X$)?

Comment: If you can embed the completion into $X$ so that the embedding is the identity on $S$, then it's always $\overline{S}$. But a completion need not be embeddable in that way. Consider on $S = (-\pi,\pi) \subset \mathbb{R}$ the two metrics $d_1(x,y) = \lvert x-y\rvert$ and $d_2(x,y) = \lvert e^{ix} - e^{iy}\rvert$. Both induce the standard topology, $S$ is totally bounded for both. But the completion with respect to $d_1$ is (isometrically isomorphic to) $[-\pi,\pi] \subset \mathbb{R}$, while the completion with respect to $d_2$ is a circle $S^1$, which can't be embedded into $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80232/discussion-between-bigbearzzz-and-daniel-fischer).

Comment: @DanielFischer I am sorry for bothering you but one of your previous comment piqued my interest. You said that we can show the metrisability of relatively weakly compact subsets using only that  $X′$ contains a countable separating set. Why is that enough? I thought I understood it but I actually didn't.

Comment: Let $\{ f_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ be a countable separating set. Then $$d(x,y) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} 2^{-n} \frac{\lvert f_n(x) - f_n(y)\rvert}{1 + \lvert f_n(x) - f_n(y)\rvert}$$ defines a metric on $X$, and the topology induced by $d$ is coarser than the weak topology. So if we have a weakly compact subset $K$, the topology induced by $d$ on $K$ and the subspace topology of the weak topology coincide.

Comment: The family of characteristic functions of dyadic cubes on $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ is an example of such a set, right? Here I am viewing $X=L^1(\Omega)$

Comment: Yes, it is. That family would also work for $X = L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ by the way. Generally, if $X$ is (isometrically isomorphic to) the dual of a separable $Y$, a countable set spanning a dense subspace of $Y$ gives a countable separating set in $X' \cong Y''$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflexivity isn't the right kind of condition for metrizability of the weak topology. Instead we have the following result.

> **Lemma:** Let $X$ be a normed space. The relative weak topology on the unit ball $B_X$ of $X$ is metrizable if and only if $X^*$ is separable.

In particular, if $X$ is reflexive but has non-separable dual then we can conclude that your first claim about boundedness of $S$ being enough in reflexive spaces is false.

It also follows from the lemma that no set with non-empty interior (in the norm topology) can be weakly metrizable if $X^*$ is not separable. If such a set were metrizable, we could fit a homeomorphic image of $B_X$ into it and then, since a subspace of a metrizable space is metrizable, we would have that $B_X$ is metrizable.

In the particular case $X = W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ we have that $X^* = W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ is not separable and so $B_X$ (and hence any set with non-empty interior in the norm topology) is not metrizable for the weak topology.

Comment: Thanks, this is probably the theorem that I remember (minus the separability part). I am particularly interested in the case where $S$ is norm-compact, do you happen to know any result related to this case?

Comment: @BigbearZzz I think Daniel Fischer's latest comment answers your question